# Modify a CNContact's properties in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I have a `User` model item, and I want to use this `User` information to create a contact that can be shared through a `UIActivityController`. This is currently not possible because the properties of `CNContact`s are read-only:

```
if let name = user?.firstName {
    contact.givenName = name
}

if let lastName = user?.lastName {
    contact.familyName = lastName
}

if let companyRole = user?.companyRole {
    contact.jobTitle = companyRole
}

if let company = user?.company {
    contact.organizationName = company
}
```

Is it possible to create a contact? I don't see any constructs/initializers that allow me to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with a `CNMutableContact` instead of a `CNContact`. That way, the properties will be modifiable.

Comment: Awesome, let's see if I can manage to share it via a `UIActivityController` now